# Python tkinter, how to display the message one by one

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using tkinter (Python version 3.9) to build an application. In the application, I want the message can be shown one by one according to the progress of the program. However, my application now can only print all the messages together.

The example code is listed as below:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk


def start():
    txt_edit.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    for _ in range(10):
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, f"\nmessage should be printed out one by one")
        # do something here
        time.sleep(0.5)
        # job done


window = tk.Tk()
window.title("User Interface")
window.rowconfigure(0, minsize=40, weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(1, minsize=200, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1, minsize=200, weight=1)

lbl_1 = tk.Label(master=window, text="Question: ")
lbl_2 = tk.Label(
    master=window, text="How to print the text out one by one?", anchor="w"
)
lbl_1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ns")
lbl_2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

txt_edit = tk.Text(window, relief=tk.SUNKEN, bd=2)
fr_buttons = tk.Frame(window)
btn_open = tk.Button(master=fr_buttons, text="Start", command=start)
btn_open.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="ew", padx=5, pady=5)

fr_buttons.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ns")
txt_edit.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

window.mainloop()
```

What is the solution to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65954799/7519434

Comment: Add `txt_edit.update()` before `time.sleep(0.5)`.

Comment: @Henry, thanks for your help. The solution to this question is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `time.sleep()` from tkinter applications isn't a good idea. Your `mainloop` and `time.sleep()` are conflicting. Your program works fine, but the changes are not displayed.

The easiest solution is updating the screen. But as I said, you should avoid using `time.sleep()`. The following solution satisfies your question, though it freezes your program and will not work on a larger application.

```
def start():
    global window
    txt_edit.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    for _ in range(10):
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, f"\nmessage should be printed out one by one")
        # do something here
        time.sleep(0.5)
        window.update() # show changes
        # job done
```

I would recommend dropping the `time` module. You can use a `timer` instead. Also, take into account the `while loop`. You might want to use `multi-threading` inside your applications.  Here's a simple `Timer` object and implementation:

```
class Timer:
    # --- Timer object ---
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = None
        self.on = False

    def start(self):
        # start counting
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.on = True

    def value(self):
        # --- return current value ---
        if self.on:
            return time.time() - self.start_time
        else:
            return 0

    def stop(self):
        # --- stop counting ---
        self.__init__()

def start():
    txt_edit.delete(1.0, tk.END)
    msg_count = 0
    timer = Timer()
    timer.start()
    while msg_count != 10:
        window.update()
        if timer.value() > 0.5:
            txt_edit.insert(tk.END, f"\nmessage should be printed out one by one")
            timer.start()
            msg_count += 1
    timer.stop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and solution! The time module is something that I want to simulate the processing. And I want to show that the message is not shown one by one. That part is actually not in the application code. But thanks for your kind recommendation! The window.update() works! Thanks!