# I want each letter of my title to appear one by one

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I am trying to get it to add a letter each time.
I have a working method but I am sure there is a simpler way using a for loop.

```
def set_title():
    global x
    window.after(x,titleset)


def titleset():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="C")
    window.after(x, titleset_a)
def titleset_a():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CA")
    window.after(x, titleset_e)
def titleset_e():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAE")
    window.after(x, titleset_s)
def titleset_s():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAES")
    window.after(x, titleset_a2)
def titleset_a2():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAESA")
    window.after(x, titleset_r)
def titleset_r():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAESAR")
    window.after(x, titleset_101)
def titleset_101():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAESAR'")
    window.after(x, titleset_s1)
def titleset_s1():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAESAR'S")
    window.after(x, titleset_c2)
```

<it goes on but thats enough to get my point across

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but I am sure there is a simpler way using a for loop." - Okay, so **what is your question** about this? Did you try to write a for loop to solve the problem? If you did, where exactly did you get stuck? Do you know how to write a `for` loop at all? What do you think should happen each time through the loop?

Comment: Did you do a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=tkinter+letters+appear+one+by+one) for your question? There's one on [StackExchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66045834/python-tkinter-how-to-display-the-message-one-by-one) that seems to be your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `after` method to request that a function be called after a delay. That function can reschedule itself to run, creating a time-based loop.

Here's a solution that passes a widget and a string to such a function. The function will pull one character off of the string, add it to the widget, and then arrange for itself to be called again until all characters have been displayed.

```
def titleset(label, string):
    current_title = label.cget("text")
    label.configure(text=current_title + string[0])
    if len(string) > 1:
        label.after(500, titleset, label, string[1:])
```

Here is a complete program using this function:

```
import tkinter as tk

def titleset(label, string):
    current_title = label.cget("text")
    label.configure(text=current_title + string[0])
    if len(string) > 1:
        label.after(500, titleset, label, string[1:])

root = tk.Tk()

title="Hello, world!"
title_label = tk.Label(root, width=len(title))
title_label.pack(side="top")

titleset(title_label, title)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes this works perfect so far. As I said its possible manually but it takes alot of time. Any chance you could sort of explain why this works? I'm learning python and I have a rough idea of how it works but I dont fully get it. Thanks

Comment: @dylanobrien: the first time `titleset` is called, the current value of the label is an empty string. So, the first letter of the passed-in string is put on the label. Then, because the string is longer than one character, we arrange for the same function to be called again in the future, but it passes in all but the first character in the string. This keeps repeating, passing a shorter and shorter string to the function until the string is just a single character. That gets added to the label and then the function isn't called again.

Comment: Yep I get it now. Appreciate the help!!!.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example solution using a `for` loop and `tkinter.after`

```
import tkinter as tk


def write_name() -> None:
    global index  # allow this function to update the value of 'index'
    index += 1  # increment the index
    label.config(text=name[0:index])  # update the label
    loop = root.after(250, write_name)  # call this function again after 250mS
    if index == len(name):  # when the entire 'name' string has been written out...
        root.after_cancel(loop)  # stop calling 'write_name'


root = tk.Tk()
name = "CAESAR'S"
index = 0
label = tk.Label(root, text='')  # create an empty label
label.pack()
write_name()  # begin updating the label


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()  # start the app
```

Comment: Typo error change this `if __name__ == '__main__';`  to `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Happy to help! As @booboo said, if one of these answers works best for you, please accept it by clicking the check mark button. And naturally, upvotes are always appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```py
title_index = 0

def set_title():
    global x, title_index

    title_index = 0
    window.after(x, titleset)

def titleset():
    global x, title_index

    title = "CAESAR'S"
    title_label.config(title[:title_index+1])
    if title_index < len(title):
        title_index += 1
        root.after(x, titleset)
```

Comment: Don't thank me. If one of the answers is the best answer that satisfies your question, then you should *accept* it and upvote it. For the other good answers, an upvote would probably be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
but I am sure there is a simpler way using a for loop.
```

If this is what you want, like this. It will repeatedly.

- I change this  `window.after(x, titleset_c2)` to `window.after(x, titleset)`
- I add `x = 1000` for delay.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *
x = 1000
 
window = Tk()
def set_title():
    global x
    window.after(x,titleset)

def titleset():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="C")
    window.after(x, titleset_a)
    
def titleset_a():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CA")
    window.after(x, titleset_e)
    
def titleset_e():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAE")
    window.after(x, titleset_s)
    
def titleset_s():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAES")
    window.after(x, titleset_a2)
    
def titleset_a2():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAESA")
    window.after(x, titleset_r)
    
def titleset_r():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAESAR")
    window.after(x, titleset_101)
    
def titleset_101():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAESAR'")
    window.after(x, titleset_s1)
    
def titleset_s1():
    global x
    title_label.config(text="CAESAR'S")
    window.after(x, titleset)

title_label = Label(window)
title_label.grid()

set_title()
window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

working code for me:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

root = tk.Tk()

title = 'CAESAR\'S'

for i in range(len(title)):
    root.title(title[:i+1])
    root.update()
    sleep(1)
```

Comment: Just a heads-up: using `sleep` in a tkinter app is a bad idea since the rest of the UI will hang while `sleep`ing. It's better to leverage the `after` method so the tkinter event loop can still run!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use only one function with `.after()` to achieve what you want:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def set_title(title, idx=0, delay=200):
    if idx < len(title):
        idx += 1
        title_label.config(text=title[:idx])
        window.after(delay, set_title, title, idx, delay)

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("400x200")
title_label = tk.Label(window)
title_label.pack(fill="x")
# start the title animation
set_title("This title will be shown character by character")
window.mainloop()
```